# How to determine that the webcam got turned on using C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Basically the process is that the site uses the webcam to take a picture and verify it. Here in unit testing, at times the webcam takes little bit extra time to turn on and take photo. Before this happens the testing jumps this step and test fails. Below I have attached the code for your reference.

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("FACE RECOGNITION")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
            
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'CAPTURE')]")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(3000);

Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/img")).Displayed);
Assert.IsFalse(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']//div[3]/span")).Displayed);

var confirmClockIn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'CONFIRM')]"));
var script = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);";
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript(script, confirmClockIn);
Thread.Sleep(3000);

confirmClockIn.Click();
```

How to overcome this problem?? Any idea?
Any improvement to the code? Or Any other way to handle this situation?

Comment: Is there a consistent line of code where the test fails?

Comment: At times the webcam takes little bit extra time to turn on and take photo. Before this happens the testing jumps this step and test fails. @GregBurghardt This happen in the third line "CAPTURE" gets clicked before the camera turns on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can determine if the webcam was turned on, but you can certainly attempt to interact with it until something succeeds, or it times out. Typically an explicit wait provides a more stable test.

The first thing I like to do is add an extension method to WebDriverWait that allows you to attempt a `void` method call until it succeeds (this will get used later to attempt to click on something):

```
public static class WebDriverWaitExtensions
{
    public static void Until(this WebDriverWait wait, Action<IWebDriver> action)
    {
        wait.Until(driver =>
        {
            action(driver);

            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

BTW, this is a good general purpose extension method to copy and paste in between projects.

Next, you'll need to alter your existing code to "wait until" certain method calls succeed:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.LinkText("FACE RECOGNITION")).Click());
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'CAPTURE')]")).Click());
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/img")).Displayed);
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']//div[3]/span")).Displayed);

var confirmClockIn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'CONFIRM')]"));
var script = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);";
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

js.ExecuteScript(script, confirmClockIn);
wait.Until(d => confirmClockIn.Click());
```

Basically, any time the test "skips ahead" before it should, introduce an explicit wait.